# Saber cuando addChildEventListener ha terminado

Tags: android, firebase, cardview

Tengo una aplicación android en la cual tengo un Fragment que contiene un CardView. Los datos del CardView son datos de eventos que tengo guardados en Firebase.
El problema que tengo es que al cargar el Fragment hay veces que se muestra vacío debido a que aun no ha cargado todos los datos de Firebase y tarda unos segundos en aparecer el CardView con todos los datos. Por este motivo he pensado introducir un ProgressDialog para mostrar un mensaje de espera hasta que termine de ejecutarse la carga de datos y una vez los haya cargado todos este se quite.

He intentado ponerlo dentro del método pero no consigo que funcione.
Os enseño mi método para cargar los datos de Firebase (La carga de datos funciona perfectamente).

```
private void cargarEventosDisponibles() {
        progressCargarEventos.setMessage("Cargando Eventos Disponibles.Por favor espere...");
        progressCargarEventos.show();
        listEventosDisponibles = new ArrayList<>();

        databaseEventos.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                Evento evento = dataSnapshot.getValue(Evento.class);
                listEventosDisponibles.add(evento);
                adaptador.setListaEventos(listEventosDisponibles);
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Evento evento = dataSnapshot.getValue(Evento.class);
                listEventosDisponibles.remove(evento);
                adaptador.setListaEventos(listEventosDisponibles);
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        progressCargarEventos.dismiss();
    }
```

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los eventos que contienen Value son ejecutados luego de los eventos de child, lo que podes hacer es generar con la misma referencia un listener para cuando tus eventos child terminen, por ejemplo

```
//Aca sabemos que los eventos child terminaron
    databaseEventos.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
          progressCargarEventos.dismiss();
        }
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
    });

    databaseEventos.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    Evento evento = dataSnapshot.getValue(Evento.class);
                    listEventosDisponibles.add(evento);
                    adaptador.setListaEventos(listEventosDisponibles);


                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Evento evento = dataSnapshot.getValue(Evento.class);
                    listEventosDisponibles.remove(evento);
                    adaptador.setListaEventos(listEventosDisponibles);

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }
```

De esa forma, cada vez que un evento child haga una accion, el evento `addValueEventlistener` se va a disparar actualizando tu adaptador, de esa forma podes estar seguro cuando termino de cargar los valores en ciertos hijos.

Comment: Siii ahora si que funciona muchísimas gracias. No sabia yo eso de que un método se lanzaba siempre antes que otros y demás pero bueno lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima vez. Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: Gastón, te hago una consulta rápida en cuanto a la solución que propones (muy bonita por cierto). Los datos vienen una sola vez desde Firebase y se ejecutan los dos listener? o los trae por ValueEventListener y ChildEventListener? Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Un evento con child solo se va a ejecutar cuando haya un cambio en la referencia de los tipos que ofrece por ejemplo onChildAdded se va a ejecutar solo cuando se agregué un hijo dentro de la referencia , el valueeventlistener se va ejecutar cuando haya un cambio en la referencia completa

Answer (score 0):

No puedes saber mediante child event listener cuantos child va a traer, y al ejecutar `progressCargarEventos.dismiss()` fuera de la llamada a Firebase y al ser esta última asincrónica se va a ejecutar inmediatamente después de `progressCargarEventos.show()` (por lo que no se va a mostrar).

Sino son muchos datos (100/1000 lo he probado y me funcionó lo más bien) puedes utilizar (en vez de `ChildEventListener`) `ValueEventListener`, ya que trae todos los datos juntos y uno de los métodos es la cantidad de Childs que trajo. Recorrer con un for cada children del snapshot de Firebase (está perfectamente explicado en su documentación) y al final del for hacer el dismiss del progress dialog.

Espero que te sirva. Es una solución menos escalable que la que propones pero más factible para interactuar con el usuario. Saludos!